# Wald F test vs Wald T test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, wald-test

What is the difference between the Wald F test and Wald T test? I understand one uses the T distribution and the other an F distribution but I am unsure in which situations one is appropriate and the other is not. What is the null hypothesis for each and can anyone give examples where a Wald T test would be appropriate but a Wald F test would not and vice versa?

Comment: Does this help? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137505/t-test-vs-f-test

Comment: This would be a better question if you defined the two tests in question, and provided a context where any distinction between the two tests might have practical consequences. // You might find [this Wicipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test) if you're not sure what the 'Wald` tests are.